# unable to initialise tensorflow AdamOptimizer with custom var_list

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

This is part of a more complex model (this is the autoencoder-part):

```
autoweights = {
    'encoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, num_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1, num_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_2, num_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1, num_input])),
}
autobiases = {
    'encoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input])),
}
```

i then collect my variables:

```
aut_params = [ k for k in autoweights] + [ k for k in autobiases]
```

an pass them to AdamOptimizer

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
    learning_rate=1e-4, 
    beta1=0.5, 
    beta2=0.9
).minimize(loss, var_list=aut_params)
```

then I get a weird error I don't understand:

```
~/Documents/ML/OutlierGAN/outlierganv1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in _get_processor(v)
    149 def _get_processor(v):
    150   """The processor of v."""
--> 151   if v.op.type == "VarHandleOp":
    152     return _DenseResourceVariableProcessor(v)
    153   if isinstance(v, variables.Variable):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'op'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have dictionaries with your variables, i.e. key:TensorFlowVariable, you are building the list with the keys of those variables, which are strings and not the values: which are the actual TensorFlow objects. Hence the `str has no attribute...`

Comment: you can select it as answer ;).
Also let me know if that worked, since I could not see what did you define as `loss`

Comment: there is a 9-minute timeframe until I can select the answer. I have it open, no worry ;)